# Safari Web Extension :hover unexpected behavior

Tags: css, safari, safari-extension

Elements with css `:hover` property is behaving very strangely in Safari extension's popup window. It looks like there is a "phantom" second cursor that follows the main cursor but with an offset and causes `:hover` on elements.

You can check this video: https://vimeo.com/673013736

I understand this is a bug in Safari, but maybe someone has a workaround?

Comment: Hi Vldmir. Please recheck the hyperlink you added in the question. The link instead opens to a 'Hair Wolf' video.

Comment: I have updated the link thanks.

Comment: Yes, it's a Safari Bug. Since the bug is in the application itself, it can't be fixed by changing the HTML/CSS/JS code. You can try this in an older version of Safari to see if its fixed, or wait for a new update. All The Best!

Comment: @SatyamMishra based on what do you claim it is a bug? any links to bug reports?

Comment: I can claim that because I can see that the hovering action appears when you hover out of the popup. `:hover`state of an element in popup can't be activated out of the popup, but here's it's happening. Also, if the same code is working in other browsers perfectly, then, it's clear that it's a browser bug. My experience also makes noise to the fullest that it's a browser bug.